# Run bash command and kill it if it exceeds specific time

Tags: bash, shell

I need to execute bash command that may take a long time, but I need to kill it if this time exceeds 5 minutes for example!

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command. For example

```
timeout 300 some_cmd
```

will kill `some_cmd` if it's still running after 300 seconds.